# Change decimal and thousand separator in Open XML for Excel files

Tags: excel, openxml

I'm trying to generate an Excel file using Open XML. Sometimes I need the numeric values on each cell to be displayed with the american separator pattern - comma for thousand, dot for decimal. By default, open XML will show me those values in the portuguese pattern - dot for thousand, comma for decimal.

Is there a property in open XML that would work as if I were going to Excel Options, Advanced and changing the separators for all numeric values in the file?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the OpenXML format always stores numbers with decimal dots (and no separator for thousands).  Excel makes the conversion when opening those files based on the setting of the user.